# Resume supported php proxy?

Tags: php, proxy, webproxy

I need to create a resume supported php proxy for large file downloading. I try to use some famous open source proxy scripts like PHProxy and CGIProxy. but they aren't resume supported.
So I want to know what is the best solution to do this?

Comment: Can you specify a little better what exactly you mean? Give as much context and usage examples as possible.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific with your issue please? What do you mean with resume supported and what solutions have you tried to implement in what way?

Comment: i.e: when I generate direct download links, my website visitors couldn't download them because of Internet Filtering. So I decide to generate my download links using Proxy and do this by using PHProxy Script and result works well but My generated download links aren't resumable. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Why do you need resume ? You can down load the files in different fragment then merge it together